# Limit Form Submission for user only one time per day

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to develop a attendance form for hr management system. I want to limit every register user per day one submission. Next day I mean after 12.00 am user will submit form again. how can i do this using php or Is there any way?
Date will be automatically insert but time is insert by user.
This is my form code:

```
    <?php

                    if($_POST)
                    {
                        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
                        $timein = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["timein"]);
                        $timeout = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["timeout"]);
                        $date = date("d, F Y");
                        $workinghours = abs($timein-$timeout);


                                $res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO timeclock SET usr='".$uid."', timein='".$timein."', timeout='".$timeout."', date='".$date."', workinghours='".$workinghours."'");
                                if($res){
                                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissable\">
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>    

                                Successfully!

                                </div>";

                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\">
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>    

                                Some Problem Occurs, Please Try Again. 

                                </div>";
                                }

                    }
                    ?>

<form name='test' action="" method="post" >

<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.5.10/js/ripples.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.5.10/js/material.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/master/dist/js/material.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#time').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker
        ({
            date: false,
            shortTime: true,
            format: 'HH:mm'
        });

    });
    </script>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label right"> <strong>Check In</strong></label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" id="time" name="timein" class="form-control floating-label" placeholder="Check In Time">
          </div>
          </div>

          <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#time2').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker
        ({
            date: false,
            shortTime: true,
            format: 'HH:mm'
        });

    });
    </script>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label right"> <strong>Check Out</strong></label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" id="time2" name="timeout" class="form-control floating-label" placeholder="Check Out Time">
          </div>
          </div>



  <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">SUBMIT</button>

  </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be it will work:

```
<?php

                    if($_POST)
                    {
                        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
                        $timein = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["timein"]);
                        $timeout = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["timeout"]);
                        $date = date("d, F Y");
                        $workinghours = abs($timein-$timeout);

                        $nnn = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timeclock WHERE usr='".$uid."' and date='".$date."'"));
                        if($nnn[0]>="1"){
                            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\">
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>    

                                Today Already Added, Please Try Again Tomorrow.  

                                </div>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                $res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO timeclock SET usr='".$uid."', timein='".$timein."', timeout='".$timeout."', date='".$date."', workinghours='".$workinghours."'");
                                if($res){
                                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissable\">
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>    

                                Successfully!

                                </div>";

                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\">
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>    

                                Some Problem Occurs, Please Try Again. 

                                </div>";
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```